# Why Hibernate doesn't support UNION?

Tags: hibernate, hql

*What is reason for hibernate not supporting **UNION** Operation ?*

(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);

Answer (score 1):

Neither JPA nor Hibernate support it. But you can always use a native SQL query for this purpose and map the `ResulSet` to entities if that's what you want.

Comment: EclipseLink [supports](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/j_union.htm) it.

Comment: For scalar queries only. However, as I explained in [my book](https://leanpub.com/high-performance-java-persistence?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=profile), you don't need to use JPQL exclusively.